# Using a parameter in time() gives you incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

Why is it when you use this

```
struct utmp rec;
```

(although, using any variable declared as type time_t would also demostrate this problem ie declaring "time_t rec;" )

this is ok -

```
rec.ut_time = time(NULL);
```

But not this -

```
time(&rec.ut_time);
```

The second line of code has the error *passing argument 1 of `time` from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]*

It is a c code file and I am using gcc to compile on Ubuntu.

The man page for `time()` states -

> ```
> time_t time(time_t *tloc);
> ```
>
> If `tloc` is non-NULL, the return value is  also  stored  in  the  memory pointed to by tloc. But then, under Bugs: The `tloc` argument is obsolescent and should always be NULL in new code. When `tloc` is NULL, the call cannot fail.

In a (2003) linux programming text book I am using, they are using the method `time(&rec.ut_time);`
And the time function with a parameter is what I see in a lot of older github examples.

But do newer versions of compliers have an issue with passing an argument in `time()` ?

Maybe I am focusing too much on this, and should just use `rec.ut_time = time(NULL);`  as it works.

Comment: Problem with `rec.ut_time` is that it's not a `time_t` type. Problem with `time_t rec;` does not seem to duplicate [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6d3sfh).

Comment: @dxiv thanks. I thought I tested it with time_t rec;  and it had the same error. But I was wrong. The issue with rec.ut_time not being a time_t type looks to be spot on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is wrong, of course. The [Linux `utmp(5)` manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html) states that the struct `utmp.ut_tv` is not of type compatible with `struct timeval`

> Note that on biarch platforms, that is, systems which can run
> both 32-bit and 64-bit applications (x86-64, ppc64, s390x, etc.),
> `ut_tv` is the same size in 32-bit mode as in 64-bit mode.  The
> same goes for `ut_session` and `ut_time` if they are present.  This
> allows data files and shared memory to be shared between 32-bit
> and 64-bit applications.  This is achieved by changing the type
> of `ut_session` to `int32_t`, and that of `ut_tv` to a struct with two
> `int32_t` fields `tv_sec` and `tv_usec`.  Since `ut_tv` may not be the
> same as `struct timeval`, then instead of the call:
>
> ```
> gettimeofday((struct timeval *) &ut.ut_tv, NULL);
> ```
>
> the following method of setting this field is recommended:
>
> ```
> struct utmp ut;
> struct timeval tv;
>
> gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
> ut.ut_tv.tv_sec = tv.tv_sec;
> ut.ut_tv.tv_usec = tv.tv_usec;
> ```

You get the warning because `ut_time` is defined as a macro that expands to `ut_tv.tv_sec`; and the `tv_sec` member of `rec.ut_tv` is `int32_t` even on systems that have 64-bit `time_t` and whose *`struct timeval`* would contain `time_t tv_sec`.

The proper way of setting the time is with `gettimeofday` as above because it would set the microsecond field too.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to check this for me. In the utmp header file, I did see that ut_time (or ut_tv.tv_sec) looked to be int32_t   But it didn't spark the light bulb in me. The utmp man page you mentioned looks to explain things well. It appears I am not the first person to run into trouble around this. Would it be true to say that in the past when only 32bit was in use, the ut_time member of struct utmp was of type time_t?

Comment: I am not sure if it was declared as `time_t` but at least it would have been compatible, which is the reason why warning didn't happen. And as the man pages say, it needs to match the storage of the record on disk so... we come back to "perhaps it should be good idea to never read entire structs from disk with `fread`"...

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps people, I will show here the complete function from the text book (Understanding Unix/Linux Programming. Molay). With the problem code corrected (code lines are commented as "added code" and "problem code").

```
/* Marks a utmp record as logged out. Does not blank the username or
remote host. Returns -1 on error, 0 on success.
*/
int logout_tty(char *line) {    
    int fd;
    struct utmp rec;
    struct timeval tv; // added code. for use within gettimeofday(). 
    int len = sizeof(struct utmp);
    int retval = -1; // assume an error

    if ((fd = open(UTMP_FILE, O_RDWR)) == -1) {
        perror(UTMP_FILE);
        return -1;
    }
    
/* note on utmp and time(). Originally tried using time() to set the time to
ut_tv.tv_sec in the while loop below. time() expects a type time_t. 
But ut_tv.tv_sec in struct utmp is int32_t . Because of this the utmp man page
recommends the use of gettimeofday() instead of time().
*/
    // search and replace
    while (read(fd, &rec, len) == len) {
        if (strncmp(rec.ut_line, line, sizeof(rec.ut_line)) == 0) {
            rec.ut_type = DEAD_PROCESS; // set type
            //if (time(&rec.ut_time) != -1) // problem code. set time
            if ((gettimeofday(&tv, NULL)) != -1) { // added code. set time
                rec.ut_tv.tv_sec = tv.tv_sec; // added code                       
                if (lseek(fd, -len, SEEK_CUR) != -1) { // back up
                    if (write(fd, &rec, len) == len) { // update
                        retval = 0; // success
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        retval = -1;
    }
    
    return retval;
}
```